# MySQL DELETE query with INNER JOIN gives error

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

This SELECT statement works:

```
SELECT *
FROM mailing
INNER JOIN NoMail ON mailing.EmailAddress = NoMail.EmailAddress
```

But this DELETE doesn't:

```
DELETE *
FROM mailing
INNER JOIN NoMail ON mailing.EmailAddress = NoMail.EmailAddress
```

I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>   '* FROM mailing INNER JOIN NoMail ON mailing.EmailAddress = NoMail.EmailA' at line 1

Comment: Take out the `*`? If that does not work, replace it with the table_names (comma separated) instead.

Comment: What I did is replace the asterisk with the actual table name: